# T-SQL syntax: is "LIKE '%'" legitimate?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-like

I could have experimented this had I access to a SQL Server instance or other SQL database.

Anyway I came across this SQL server stored procedure, in which there is a factually statement like:

```
some_field LIKE '%'
```

I think this is a legitimate statement but what will it return? My take is no matter what the value of *some_field* is, it always returns TRUE.

Comment: Unless it's `null`.

Comment: I.e. that's the same as `some_field IS NOT NULL`.

Comment: You can always try for yourself on https://dbfiddle.uk/

Comment: It'll result in the same as `IS NOT NULL`, but it'll be far slower as it isn't SARGable.

Comment: `some_field` I guess is shorthand for `some_column`? :)

Comment: If it was followed by `ESCAPE '%'` then it won't match anything

Answer (score 3):

```
some_field LIKE '%'
```

Will return all values except null. It's the same as:

```
some_field IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: I'm not sure why this would be downvoted.

Comment: Thanks a lot @GordonLinoff.

Comment: Interestingly it matches an empty string also, which is logical when you look at the docs.

Comment: If this answer helped you please accept it. So that this question can be marked as answered. Thanks